# Zend view , Plugin not found

Tags: zend-framework, zend-view

i am creating email templates using the zend view class, and assigning variables..
i am also using helpers withing the view script file, but it has the errors when rendered:

```
Message: Plugin by name 'EmTpl' was not found in the registry; used paths: Zend_View_Helper_: Zend/View/Helper/:/application/modules/customers/views/helpers/
```

however, this plugin exists when i use the on dispatch, as in loading a controller with a view script that loads this helper called 'EmTpl'.

this is my script for emails:

```
    $html = new \Zend_View();
    $html->setScriptPath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/modules/admin/views/scripts/emails/');
    //$html->addHelperPath('Zend/View/Helper/','Zend_View_Helper_');
    $html->addHelperPath(
            APPLICATION_PATH . '/modules/customers/views/helpers/','Zend_View_Helper_'
    );


    $html->render("customer-new.phtml");
```

and inside my customer-new.phtml,

theres:

```
<body>
hello, <?=$this->name?>
<?=$this->emTpl?>
</body>
```

this plugin works fine when called in controller view scripts... 
but i want it to work with my email templates script.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

you have to add helper paths before you set the script path...